# How to generate random data based on some criteria in R

Tags: r

I wan to generate 300 random data based on the following criteria:

```html
Class   value
0   1-8
1   9-11
2   12-14
3   15-16
4   17-20
```

Logic: when class = 0, I want to get random data between 1-8. Or when class= 1, I want to get random data between 9-11 and so on.

This gives me the following hypothetical table as an example:

```html
   

 Class  Value
    0   7
    0   4
    1   10
    1   9
    1   11
    .   .
    .   .
```

I want to have equal and unequal mixtures in each class

Comment: Since you skip the values between 8 and 9, I wonder.  Do you just want integers?  Do you want an equal mixture of each class?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they are integers. I want to have equal and unequal mixtures in each class.

Comment: @user330 please don't do that. This site exists to act as a repository of knowledge to help others, and your question is a part of that. Please clarify your question and I will do my best to improve the answer.

Comment: I know that. I really thank you for your behaviour and help.

Comment: So if there are 300 samples, you want a fixed number of each class (60 each of 0-4), and within each class you want integers drawn from the target range, but you want an equal number of each random integer within each class? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Assume for 300 samples, 60 go to class 0, 60 go to class 1, 60 go to class 2 and so on.

Comment: @user330 that's what my example does at the moment.

Comment: A bit different, I think we need to define probability conditions?

Comment: Thanks, Allan, for your help; I have already upvoted you. The solution @PavoDive is great for me.

Comment: I'm glad you got there with a bit of perseverance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing some additional flexibility in the code, so that different probabilities can be used in the sampling, and having the smallest possible amount of hard-coded values:

```
# load data.table
library(data.table)

# this is the original data
a = structure(list(Class = 0:4, value = c("1-8", "9-11", "12-14", 
"15-16", "17-20")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

# this is to replace "-" by ":", we will use that in a second
a[, value := gsub("\\-", ":", value)]

# this is a vector of EQUAL probabilities
probs = rep(1/a[, uniqueN(Class)], a[, uniqueN(Class)])

# This is a vector of UNEQUAL Probabilities. If wanted, it should be 
# uncommented and adjusted manually
# probs = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.25)

# This is the number of Class samples wanted
numberOfSamples = 300

# This is the working horse
a[sample(.N, numberOfSamples, TRUE, prob = probs), ][, 
           smpl := apply(.SD, 
                         1, 
                         function(x) sample(eval(parse(text = x)), 1)), 
           .SDcols = "value"][, 
                  .(Class, smpl)]
```

What is good about this code?

- If you change your classes, or the value ranges, the only change you need to be concerned about is the original data frame (`a`, as I called it)
- If you want to use uneven probabilities for your sampling, you can set them and the code still runs.
- If you want to take a smaller or larger sample, you don't have to edit your code, you only change the value of a variable.

Comment: @ PavoDive I don't get Class 0-4 for 17-20; not sure what its reason is. Could we do better?

Comment: You're right. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
df <- data.frame(Class = sample(0:4, 300, TRUE))

df$Value <- sapply(list(1:8, 9:11, 12:14, 15:16, 17:20)[df$Class + 1],
                   sample, size = 1)
```

This gives you a data frame with 300 rows and appropriate numbers for each class:

```r
head(df)
#>   Class Value
#> 1     0     3
#> 2     1    10
#> 3     4    19
#> 4     2    12
#> 5     4    19
#> 6     1    10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, two issues, a lack of an equal mixture and a lack of sample size, i.e., 300. Kindly see my comment above

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update your codes?

Comment: @user330 I thought you wanted to supply the class numbers and generate the appropriate values based on your specification. In my example above, I supplied a random vector for `Class`, but obviously you would supply your own values for `Class`- for example, `rep(0:4, each = 60)` would give you 300 random values. As for an equal measure, could you please explain a bit more about what you mean?